# PDF document with notes has yellow squares, can't remove them

Tags: pdf, preview

I have a PDF document with a lot of notes. There is a yellow square in every note, and if I remove the note using the inspector, the yellow squares doesn't go away:

[image]

I need to print this document and it's unusable with all these yellow squares. How do I remove them?

PS: **I already removed the notes**, but there are still yellow squares.

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the document so we can see what can be done with it?

Comment: @user3439894 Here is it: http://docdro.id/xzLyXSE

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here is how you can remove the notes from the linked document.

1. Open the linked document in Preview.
2. <kbd>control</kbd> click on the note icon and select Delete Annotation.

Or:

1. Open the linked document in Preview.
2. Click the note icon, which opens the note.
3. Press the <kbd>esc</kbd> key to dismiss the note but leave the note icon highlighted.
4. Press the <kbd>delete</kbd> key.

Or:

1. Open the linked document in Preview.
2. Click: Preview > Tools > Show Inspector
3. Click: Annotations Inspector
4. Click the Type column, so all the notes are at the top.
5. Select all the notes, then press the <kbd>delete</kbd> key.

[image: Annotations Inspector]

I've uploaded a modified copy of the [linked document here](http://docdro.id/pKME7Qi).

Comment: I already deleted the notes, the problem is that the yellow square doesn't get deleted if I delete the note.

Comment: @Ramy Al Zuhouri, All I can say is, I downloaded the linked PDF document, opened it in Preview and tested the three methods I've presented in the answer and in all cases the note icon was deleted along with its yellow color. Nothing was left behind from the deletion of the notes. The only yellow remaining in the document is in the signature field however this is not a _note_ nor did I see a way to change it. I've uploaded a modified copy of the [linked document here](http://docdro.id/pKME7Qi).

Comment: I've found out what was the problem: if I delete a note, the yellow square doesn't disappear. But if I save, close and reopen the document I don't see it anymore. It's probably a bug.

Comment: None of these methods are working for me.

Comment: None of the methods worked for me, nor DJF3's suggestion of using Fn-Delete. (I could find no way to select the yellow-square without opening it for editing, and pressing ESC while editing did nothing.)  I also tried quitting Preview and re-opening, without success.  However, I was able to delete the comments in another PDF viewer (PDF Guru), so I think this is a bug in Preview.

Comment: Third option worked for me

Comment: @Jess Riedel, I'd like to point out that my answer to this question was not meant to be a canonical answer to the issue the OP was having in general but with the explicit and specific **PDF** _file_ linked in his comment. That was the only **PDF** _document_ considered in the formulation of an answer to his immediate issue with the specific file. Also keep in mind this answer if over four years old and things do change over time. As to the possibility of _bugs_ in **Preview** or any other _software_, there are always possibilities as nothing is perfect in the computer industry! TFYC though.

Comment: Thanks user3439894.  The explicitly stated philosophy of StackExchange is to create answers that will be useful to more than one person; helping the question asker is just incidental.  Insofar as your answer is not expected to be general, we should document that, as I have done in my comment. Likewise, as software ages, so we need comments like mine to track whether answers still work.  And finally, yes, it is not surprising that bugs may sometimes appear, but it is also useful information to know that there is apparently a bug *here*.

Answer (score 7):

None of these solutions worked for me, but probably because I was using a windows keyboard, which others might have. So maybe this will help someone.

With a windows keyboard what worked was to:

If the yellow square is now minimized to a small square, just click it once and then click the BACKSPACE key... NOT the DELETE key.

So backspace is the action you want, not forward delete. Coming from Windows this change in backspace vs delete when using a native MacBook pro keyboard was a little confusing.

*** NOTE - If the yellow square is opened large, just click anywhere outside of the square and it will shrink to a small yellow square, and then you can do as I said.

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out!
Move it and then press "delete" without clicking anywhere else. You have to move it instead of trying to select it

Comment: Thank you! This has been driving me crazy.

Comment: Old problem, still not fixed by Apple. Thanks for that trick, made my day! BTW: It seems to be only the very last note that fights deletion. All other notes  can be easily deleted with backspace in the annotations side bar.

Answer (score 2):

I had this happen just now and nothing worked. I had to first quit preview, then re-open the document. Then I could delete the yellow boxes using "Delete" as expected.

This is on Preview Version 11.0 (999.4)

Answer (score 1):

MacOS 10.14.1, preview v10.1

For me the yellow boxes stayed on the screen.

The only way for me to remove them:

1. selecting the note (a gray line appears around the yellow box)
2. **press *Fn-Delete***

Answer (score 0):

My system is macOS 11.1 and I came across the same bug.

I have tried @Jess's solution ("However, I was able to delete the comments in another PDF viewer (PDF Guru), so I think this is a bug in Preview.") which works pretty well. The app I used was WPS office which could open nearly all kinds of files, for example, Word, Excel, Powerpoint, PDF, Mindmap files, just name a few. And it is free by the way.

Hope this could help you guys.