# windows pdf highlight, underline, etc come with a square in mac preview?

Tags: windows, pdf, preview

How to get rid of them in the first place? I mean, I don't want to delete them one by one as in the [other threads](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257392/pdf-document-with-notes-has-yellow-squares-cant-remove-them). I just want to know how to prevent this happening at all(may be has something to do with windows), I am using foxit reader on windows. I also tried adobe dc reader

The squares are all empty, I didn't add anything in it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a compatibility issue I think.
Same behavior happens when I copy something from MS Word 2013 to MS Word 365 (for Mac)
By the way, is it a macOS question or a Windows related question? If it's the latter, your question should not be here. :-)

Comment: I can only say this is related to mac

Comment: I think I don't understand your question quite right. :-(
So, you say:

"may be has something to do with windows"

The original document is created on a Windows machine and when you open it (in preview) on a macOS you get these boxes and...?

Comment: If that's correct, than is my answer your answer.
Compatibility issue between the 2.

Sorry my comment is in 2 pieces because I took longer than 5 minutes to write it. :-(

Comment: If compatibility is the issue, then it might be solved either on mac or windows, so this still is a mac related question.

Comment: Ok, what I mean is a compatibility issue of the 'file' that probably was created on Windows that you want to view on your Mac.
The very same issue also happens between different MS Office versions!
I'm not sure that there's a solution to that problem. :-(